# Can One Cast Spells Through an Energy Wall?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

From my understanding, a spell caster can not cast spells through a solid object. I was wondering if this means that spell casters won't be able to cast through Energy Wall, a sheet of energy formed out of unstable ectoplasm? If casters can't cast through Energy Wall, can they still cast over the wall if their spell range is long enough?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Spells that have one or more [targets](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) *can't* be cast through the sheet created by the power [*energy wall*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/e/energy-wall)

The power [*energy wall*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/e/energy-wall) creates an effect that is

> An opaque sheet of energy up to 20 ft. long/level or a ring of energy with a radius of up to 5 ft./2 levels; either form 20 ft. high

Reading on, while the sheet deals damage, the sheet possesses neither hardness nor hp, and creatures, objects, and effects traverse it unhindered (except for the damage the sheet deals). Despite the misleading name, the sheet created by the power *energy wall* is not a [wall](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/environment/dungeons#TOC-Walls) nor is it even an [obstacle](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Terrain-and-Obstacles) but a psionic effect, obeying the rules of the power itself. For example, a barbarian's greataxe can't deal damage to the sheet, and most dragons' breath weapons go right through the sheet, ignoring it completely.

The section [Aiming a Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) in the subsection Target or Targets says that

> Some spells have a target or targets. You cast these spells on creatures or objects, as defined by the spell itself. **You must be able to see** or touch **the target**, and you must specifically choose that target.

However, the sheet presents no barrier to spells that *don't* require the caster to have one or more targets, for example, most area spells.

Casting a spell *over* the sheet while remaining *behind* the sheet isn't possible unless the spell allows for it to be employed that way. Most spells *aren't* like grenades and can't be lobbed over barriers

Comment: I am under the impression that in order to cast an area effect, you need line of sight to target it.  While this implies to me that the effects could extend past the energy wall, the target square/intersection couldn't.  Is this reading incorrect?

Comment: @rStyskel I think that is incorrect: ["You must designate the location where (effects) are to appear, **either** by seeing it **or** defining it"](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell), with that *defining it* being *really* important because "[y]ou must have a clear line of effect to any target that you cast a spell on **or to any space in which you wish to create an effect.**" Emphasis mine. This mean, for example, a caster can choose to have a *fireball* spell's point of origin be inside an area of darkness through which the caster cannot see.

Comment: I've always thought of the origination intersection as the target.  So to make sure I understand, reading the targeted intersection as a "target" is incorrect in this case?

Comment: @rStyskel It might be the actual word *target* that's muddying things for you. For example, unlike the spell *charm person*, the spell *fireball* **just doesn't have** a target entry in its spell description. But a *fireball* **does** have a range and an effect entry, so the *fireball* can be cast anywhere within that range to create that effect provided the caster has line of effect to that anywhere. The spell *charm person*, on the other hand, has a target entry, requiring the caster to see (in this case) the target.